# Conflicting peer dependency - bootstrap and bootstrap-vue installation

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Get problems when initiating a new vue bootstrap project.
This is what i do, and the errors i get, any good ideas?
Chat-GPT could not help me, so now i have to rely on you :-)

`vue create my-project`

selctions:

```
Manually select features
Add "Router"
vue 2.x
Use history mode for router? - Yes
ESLint + Standard config
Lint on save
In dedicated config files
```

`npm install bootstrap bootstrap-vue`

output:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-vue@8.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-vue@"^8.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!   dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!     dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Asked Chat-GPT for support, but no solutions worked

Comment: The problem is misidentified. This is irrelevant to bootstrap-vue. It's unknown what went wrong during project init but the problem is what the error states, either upgrade `@vue/eslint-config-standard` or downgrade eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: Might be, but this happens when installing bootstrap. Please advise how to update this post then.

Comment: This should have happened if you were installing deps in any way. The problem is supposed to be reproducible if you remove node modules and reinstall. The post should contain package.json at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found post that suggested to run:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps=true --location=project
```

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4664#issuecomment-1086096726

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).